# How to get UDID of Provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I have Xcode 6.3.1 I know there was a program or a part of Xcode, what could show me the provi's UDID, but I cannot find the program. Can somebody help me? Maybe the name was like apple configurator, or some kind of this.

Thanks,

**EDIT**
Thanks for answere of chedabob I have found the program I searched for.
Here you can find iphone Configuration Utility:
http://iphone-configuration-utility.soft32.com/mac/

I have installed it on Yosemite, and it works well:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There used to be iPhone Configuration Utility but Apple stopped releasing it.

You can just open the provisioning profile in any text editor as it's mostly just a PList file, and there will be a key "guid" near the middle.

Comment: And how can I identify the exact provisioning profile? I have fifty of them on my computer. Ok, I can re-download the one I want to view from Member Center, but It would be better to see them in a program,
What's the official answere from apple for these questions?

Comment: I found it listed as UUID